# Not able to access methods inside filters - Vue.js 2.0

Tags: vuejs2

I have a filter which was working fine until I called a method inside it.

Sample Code:

```
export default {
  filters: {
    addCurrency(val){
      return this.getSymbol("rs")+val;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getSymbol(currency){
      // Some code to return appropriate symbol
    }
  }
}
```

This gives error saying `can not read property getSymbol of undefined`.